# how can i set an imageurl of a asp control dynamically. my image is present in a database in binary form

Tags: c#, asp.net

**i have an ashx file through which i want to get the imageurl for an asp image control. the code below is an ashx file**

```
  SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlDataReader dr = null; SqlCommand cmd = null;
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GalleriaDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Image from tblImage where UserName='" + context.Session["uname"] + "'");
            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Image"]);
                dr.Close();
            }
        }**
```

Comment: Ashx is a web handler which serves something and I am assuming in your case it serves an image. If you put the image Id in the url and change you code then it can serve the image with the url. I am not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: ImageId?? i didnt understand. i have only the images and name attributes  in the database . i tried giving name value as the image url as '<%#
                            "ImageHandler.ashx?name="+ Eval("name") %>' bt i dont get any images from thedatabase

Comment: By `ImageId` I meant any unique identifier that can be used to identify which image you want to retrieve. You would, of course, need to change your query so it uses that when fetching the image from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Mention the path of your ashx file in the ImageUr Property. Like below

```
<asp:Image runat='server' Id='image' ImageUrl='imageprocessor.ashx'></asp:Image>
```